# How to Exclude from migration Auto-Generated table in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

i have table Asp_net_users which is many-to-many relation with table Clients. There are no mapped object in between them, it been auto -generated by EF:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.State)
        .HasConversion<string>();

    entity.HasMany(d => d.Users)
        .WithMany(p => p.Clients)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "ClientUser",
            l => l.HasOne<AspNetUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId"),
            r => r.HasOne<Client>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ClientId"),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey("ClientId", "UserId");
                j.ToTable("client_users"); // ,"identity"
                j.IndexerProperty<string>("ClientId");
                j.IndexerProperty<string>("UserId");
            });
});
```

The code above generating table `client_users` which i don't want in my migration.

I've tried to add to code above:

```
.Metadata
.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true)
```

no luck.

I know I can exclude using this method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>().ToTable("asp_net_users", "identity", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
```

but the problem is: above mentioned table is auto generated and  I don't know how to do ToTable on it.

tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("client_users", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
```

but it don't compile. `modelBuilder.Entity()` wants to have an object.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I added `j.Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);` inside and it worked:

```
entity.HasMany(d => d.Users)
  .WithMany(p => p.Clients)
  ...
  j =>
  {
      ...
      j.Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);
  });
```